# Using mongoose.Types.ObjectId() with multiple scaled machines (Duplication issue?)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's just assume the below code will be executed many times when running a live server. If I scaled the machine to have 10 instances for example, is there a small chance the ObjectId will be duplicated when saving into mongoDb? Or will mongoDb force the _id to be different if there is duplication?

```js
// Taken from mongoose documentation!
const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
const author = new Person({
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  name: 'Ian Fleming',
  age: 50
});

author.save(() => {
  console.log('saved!')
});
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is to create an Id before I save it. I don't want to have to save documents and then collect their _ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling your server to multiple instances won't affect the value of generated `ObjectID`s such that you now have duplicate `ObjectID`s. The uniqueness of the ObjectID generated is not just a function of the time it was generated, the generator(MongoDB node driver in this case) also factors in the unique machine and process properties.

If what you want is to create the `_id` field yourself before saving documents into the DB, you can easily do that without any trouble, in fact, you don't have to use a hexadecimal string like the one generated, you can make use of string or numbers but then, you would have to ensure the uniqueness yourself.